# Box-shadow on triangles

Tags: css

```css
[class*="leaves"] {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 30px solid transparent;
    border-right: 30px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 50px solid greenyellow;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree-leaves1-1"></div>
```

It should be a simple thing I can't figure out. I am making trees with css. For the triangles(the leaves) I want there to be a shadow at the bottom, but when I apply a box-shadow, it creates the shadow around the entire box the triangle shape is nested in, is there a way to shape the shadow, or make it so it only shows at the very bottom of the box?
Here is the example in codepen. vvv
https://codepen.io/adschmidt1997/pen/xxwNRKj

Comment: use drop shadow filter

Answer (score 0):

Please run the code snippet and see if this works for you?

```css
[class*="leaves"] {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 30px solid transparent;
    border-right: 30px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 50px solid greenyellow;
    /*box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);*/
    /* offset-x | offset-y | blur-radius | spread-radius | color */
    box-shadow: 0 10px 10px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree-leaves1-1"></div>
```

Comment: THanks, that fixed it. I see what I did wrong now

Comment: Glad that it is working now.